# Issue during Checkout process with DrupalGap Commerce

Tags: commerce, javascript

I'm trying to build an app with DurpalGap and his commerce module for my ECommerce website.

I've followed your tutorial but I still have some errors (all DPM are activated) :

- The first page I made is the product list, following your example.
- When you click on a product, the product is displayed but only title, image and add to cart button (I can't reach to have the price and offer displayed... whereas it is configured in the Drupalgap Manage display product)
- Issue : cart.json doesn't exist -> I've created a JSON View of "Shopping Cart Form" and It seems to work now.
- An issue occured when you click on the add to cart button (no product ID), I've changed "field_product_entities" in the Commerce.JS (line 650 -> SKU) & (line 851 -> Field_produit_entities) and the console doesn't show the error by now.
- But now I have : "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (: You must specify a valid order ID)" / POST: https://rechargetonmob.nc/?q=drupalgap/line-item.json - 400 - / ["You must specify a valid order ID"]

How do I manage with it ?

Thanks for your help, I wish you a very nice day !
https://rechargetonmob.nc/mobile-application/index.html

Comment: `I've followed your tutorial` I don't recall creating any Commerce tutorial.